# Is It Possible to Add the SharePoint List View Related Ribbon to the Application Page?

Tags: web-part, list-view, ribbon, application-pages

Is it possible to add the list view related ribbon to the application page?

I have a list view webpart in my application page. Now I don't have any ribbon like list view web part. Is it possible to add the same ribbon in an application page?

We have the option to remove the page related ribbon and add the ribbon as same as the list view page in SharePoint.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you're referring to the List Tools Ribbon with the Items and List tabs:

[image: Default List View Ribbon]

If so, then these will show up on an application page as soon as you click on your List View Web Part:

[image: Contextual List View Ribbon]

Comment: yeah i am telling the same, i dont think it will show like this.